# Why is my word an empty String, when I split() my string with \\s

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String

```
String text = "Good morning. Have a good class. "
               + "Have a good visit. Have fun!";
```

I split it with this:

```
String[] words = text.split("[\\s\\n\\t\\r.,;:!?(){}]");
```

Loop through the array to get a `word`

```
word = words[i];
```

I'm trying to get a List of word occurrence. I print the List and I get this:

```
 [morning:1, class:1, visit:1, fun:1, a:2, good:3, :3, have:3]

 **// I have three Obvious empty Strings somewhere ^^ According the :3
```

So I add a `System.out.print(word ", ")` and get this:

```
good, morning, , have, a, good, class, , have, a, good, visit, , have, fun,

    // space ^^                 space^^                 space^^
```

Why do I get these spaces, and how do I correct it?

Comment: `"[\\s\\n\\t\\r.,;:!?(){}]+"` That `+` on the end is very important and allows multiple elements to form a single delimiter.

Comment: I made it an answer. And you're welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're splitting on each occurrence of the chars in your square bracket. Instead change it to: `"[\\s\\n\\t\\r.,;:!?(){}]+"` That `+` on the end is very important and allows multiple elements to coalesce into a single delimiter.

Comment: +1 just a little piece of information, thats (correct me if i'm wrong) a Regular Expression (regex). It's to make finding certain data easier. You can learn more about regex [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)